# How to combine 2 opus audio file using ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, opus

i have to mulitple opus files for merge(audio-mix) to one mp4.

i want to combine(audio-mix) N opus files using ffmpeg.
**The time between the two files is different, and the timeline must be aligned.**

how to this?

If ffmpeg can't do it, recommend another way.

Comment: See adelay and amix filter.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice eloquent solution:

1. Install ffmpeg
2. run `cmd` and go to the folder containing the files.
3. Run: `ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i <(for f in $PWD/*.EXT; do echo "file '$f'"; done) -codec copy full.EXT`, replacing both instances of "EXT" with the file extension used by your audiobook (mp3, m4a, etc).

You may need to copy ffmpeg into the folder if it does not want to run.